# CDC (Change Data Capture) is not harvesting logs and log file continues to grow

Tags: sql-server, replication, cdc, change-data-capture

I am in a Windows environment running a MSsql server 2014 enterprise.
I am running CDC on a DB with Always On High Availability Groups. When I first enabled CDC the log files were being harvested and CDC was working well. One day I noticed that my log file was growing very large. I noticed that no new changes ha been captured for the last day. I looked up a few reasons that would prevent CDC from harvesting logs and most point to long running transactions preventing the logs from hardening. When I run DBCC OpenTrans I get.

```
Transaction information for database 'IAmImportant'.

Replicated Transaction Information:
        Oldest distributed LSN     : (0:0:0)
        Oldest non-distributed LSN : (1458412:1642257:1)
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your
system administrator.
```

I understand when using always on high availability groups that CDC should use the log reader instead of its normal capture job, however I have dropped and re-added the capture job and it is running. I have tried to fully disable and re-enable CDC on the DB but it still does not want to harvest.

Any thoughts on how to restart harvesting of the logs?

Comment: Did the transaction ever commit in your DBCC OpenTrans message?  I am wondering if someone began a transaction but never committed it.

Comment: If i disable CDC the transaction goes away. For grins i re-enabled CDC and the transaction showed up again.

Comment: What does `sys.dm_cdc_log_scan_sessions` say? Do you have mirroring or availability groups in the environment?